# If $f(x)\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow 0^{+}$ and $g(x)\geq 1$ then $\dfrac{g(x)}{f(x)}\rightarrow\infty$ as $x\rightarrow 0^{+}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

> Prove if $f(x)\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow 0^{+}$ and $g(x)\geq 1$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$,then $\dfrac{g(x)}{f(x)}\rightarrow +\infty$ as $x\rightarrow 0^{+}$

$\underline{Attempt}$

Since $f(x) \rightarrow 0$ as $x   \rightarrow 0^{+},$

by definition $\forall  \varepsilon> 0$, $\exists 
 $ $\delta>0$ such that $0<x<\delta$ imply $|f(x)-0|=|f(x)|<\varepsilon$ ,

and also  we know $g(x) \geq 1$
for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$

so for $|f(x)| \neq0$

$$\frac{1}{\varepsilon}<\frac{1}{|f(x)|}$$

therefore we can get

$$\frac{1}{\varepsilon} <\bigg| \dfrac{g(x)}{f(x)} \bigg| $$ so in either case $$\frac{1}{\varepsilon} < \dfrac{g(x)}{f(x)}  $$

this implies  $\forall M=\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\in \mathbb{R}$ , $\exists$ $ \delta>0$ such that $\dfrac{g(x)}{f(x)}>M $ whenever $0<x<\delta$ ,so
$\dfrac{g(x)}{f(x)}\rightarrow \infty$ as $x   \rightarrow 0^{+}$

I don't know whether my attempt correct or wrong if it is not give some help and if this is correct give me how to prove $f(x)=0$ this is crazy problem  to me what happen if $f(x)=0$,

Comment: If $f(a) = 0$ then $\frac{g}{f}$ is not defined at $a$.

Comment: @Oussema If so this statement is not valid?

Comment: The statement is valid. It says nothing about the point $x=0$, only about what happens as $x\to 0^+$.

Comment: If for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $y \in (0,\epsilon)$ such that $f(y) = 0$ then yes the statement is not valid for example in the case of the function $f(x) = 0$. Otherwise, just choose an epsilon that is less than the smallest number at which $f$ is zero and the statement is valid.

Comment: I don't see how $\frac{1}{\varepsilon}<|\frac{g(x)}{f(x)}|$ implies $\frac{1}{\varepsilon}<\frac{g(x)}{f(x)}$. Also what does $\to \infty$ mean? Do you mean $\to +\infty$ or $\to -\infty$ or do you mean that the absolute value tends to $+\infty$ ?

Comment: @Gribouillis I will edit it which is $+\infty$

Comment: @Gribouillis in either case means $f(x)>0 $ and $f(x)<0$

Comment: @Gribouillis I believe in anglophone countries, they use $\infty$ instead of $+\infty$. But I agree with your point, for example if we take $f(x) = -x$ and $g(x) = 1$ then $\frac{g}{f} \to -\infty$.

Comment: @Dinush the case for which $f(x) < 0$ doesn't work as the inequality is flipped.

Comment: @Dinush, the statement of the problem is wrong, it needs to be $f(x) \to 0^+$ or $|\frac{g(x)}{f(x)}| \to + \infty$ otherwise there are counterexamples.

Comment: @Dinush take for example $f(x) = x \sin(\frac{1}{x})$ which converges to zero by the squeeze theorem, and $g(x) = 1$. $\frac{g(x)}{f(x)}$ doesn't have a limit in this case.

Comment: @Oussema I think it is thank you

Answer (score 2):

There's no need in my opinion to bother going straight into $\epsilon-\delta$. Instead, consider that:

$$g_2(x)>g_1(x)\geq 1 \overbrace{\implies}^{x<1, x\neq 0} \frac{g_2(x)}{x}>\frac{g_1(x)}{x}$$

You should prove this assertion. But, as a direct consequence of this, we note that setting $g(x)\equiv 1$ and evaluating the limit will give us the *lower bound* for the limit, as this is the smallest allowed function under the condition $g(x) \geq 1$. So now all you need to prove is that $$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{1}{f(x)}=\infty$$
and then every other function will have a greater (that is, also infinite) limit.

Comment: Thank you, (+1)

Comment: What about $f(x) = x$ if $x\in {\mathbb Q}$ and $f(x) = -x$ if $x\in {\mathbb R}\setminus{\mathbb Q}$ ?

Comment: @Gribouillis, good point, its likely the question *should be* $x\to 0^+ \implies f(x) \to 0^+$ as, as you note, the current condition is insufficient for the result.